# How can I build a Safari extension package from the command line?

Tags: macos, command-line, safari, codesign, safari-extension

Instead of going to *Extension Builder > Build Package…*, I'd like to built a `.safariextz` package from the `MyExtension.safariextension` folder.

I know I can unpack an extension with `xar -xf`. I suspect the way back involves packing it with `xar`, but then I'll need to do the code signing thing, which may or may not involve [codesign(1)](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html).

Comment: bad news? http://twitter.com/eridius/status/17227204729

Comment: Kch nailed it on the head.  Maybe someone has a hack that works?

Answer (score 6):

Here are Omar Ismail's instructions, omitting the need for separate shell scripts.  This will all occur in a directory `safari/`, where we will be signing the directory `safari/appname.safariextension/` to become the extension `safari/appname.safariextz`.  The first thing is to sign the extension the official way, with Extension Builder's `Build Package`.

Set up Xar:
1. Download and unzip/untar
https://github.com/downloads/mackyle/xar/xar-1.6.1.tar.gz
to wherever you want the executable xar-1.6.1 (xar 1.6dev doesn't support the options we need)
2. in xar-1.6.1/

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -s /full/path/to/xar-1.6.1/src/xar /usr/local/bin/xar161
```

Set up your certificates:
1. in safari/

```
mkdir certs/
xar161 -f appname.safariextz --extract-certs certs/
```

2. open Keychain Access and export your Safari Developer certificate to safari/certs/certs.p12 (use a blank password for certs.p12, and then use your Mac's password to export the cert)
3. in safari/certs/

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certs.p12 -nodes | openssl x509 -outform der -out cert.der
(same blank password)
openssl pkcs12 -in certs.p12 -nodes | openssl rsa -out key.pem
(same blank password)
openssl dgst -sign key.pem -binary < key.pem | wc -c > size.txt
```

It's possible that you can get the certificates from `certs/cert.p12`, and not need the `--extract-certs` step (and hence not need the extension built the official way), but I don't know openssl well enough, and it's only for the set up that you need that step anyway.

Once everything is set up, to sign the extension:
In safari/

```
xar161 -czf appname.safariextz --distribution appname.safariextension/
xar161 --sign -f appname.safariextz --digestinfo-to-sign digest.dat --sig-size `cat certs/size.txt` --cert-loc certs/cert.der --cert-loc certs/cert01 --cert-loc certs/cert02
openssl rsautl -sign -inkey certs/key.pem -in digest.dat -out sig.dat
xar161 --inject-sig sig.dat -f appname.safariextz
rm -f sig.dat digest.dat
```

This was all on a 2006 Snow Leopard MacBook, so it's possible things may be different on a machine that's more up to date.

Comment: I've done everything above, got no errors and warnings during this procedure, but when i try to import safariextz i get error: Safari can’t install this extension, An error occurred while installing this extension. In console i get com.apple.WebKit(41523) deny file-read-data /Applications/Safari.app. Any idea what's the problem?

Comment: Found out what the problem was. I was using absolute paths to --distribution so xar packed absolute path to my build directory inside extension package. Use relative paths when compressing with xar

Comment: Goran Radulovic: I'm getting the same error, even if path is ok. How can I open console to see error?

Comment: I believe it's impossible to do at the moment. Something has changed and Safari Developers certificate is no longer exported as `.p12` file. Otherwise, it's impossible to create corresponding keys.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like there is a way to patch XAR with a signature option. http://code.google.com/p/xar/issues/detail?id=76#c0

Comment: Nice. Will investigate further.

Comment: Some folks in that thread are reporting success! Almost time to update this aging thread