# How to pack a Safari extension programmatically?

Tags: safari, browser

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I build a Safari extension package from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423522/how-can-i-build-a-safari-extension-package-from-the-command-line)

I'm working on a web browser extension for Safari.

Is there any way to create a .safariextz package from the Linux or Mac commandline, in the same way we can do it for Firefox and Chrome extensions?

Answer (score 1):

I am looking for this too.

It seems you can use XAR with a patch.

See also:
[How can I build a Safari extension package from the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423522/how-can-i-build-a-safari-extension-package-from-the-command-line)

Comment: Thank you beltoy. I'll look into that again in a few days I think. There were two answers here saying the same but.. they disappeared. I'll let you know if I can find a solution.